EAPI encoder JSP
In our existing application we are using esapi-2.0.1.jar. And below code in jsp scriplet
ESAPI.encoder().encoder.encodeForHTML("test");

When upgrading to higher version esapi-2.2.1.0, It showing below error,

org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java::129), org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.encoder(ESAPI.java:101)

Can we use ESAPI encoder in jsp file with higher version of ESAPI?

Does this answer your question? ESAPI - Getting ClassNotFoundException with ESAPI 2.2.3.1

Since the ESAPI encoder (as well as the JSP tag library for encoding) in included in every release of the ESAPI jar, the answer is yes. That is not the problem. The most likely reason is you tried to use your old ESAPI.properties file and the property for ESAPI.Logger needs updated. The 2.2.1.0 release notes are at https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/blob/develop/documentation/esapi4java-core-2.2.1.0-release-notes.txt. Be sure to read the section "Changes Requiring Special Attention".
However, in addition, I will say that if you want support, you need to be on the most recent release. We have a very small core team (3 people) and we all have day jobs so if someone has issues with older ESAPI releases, we don't have the time to go back and investigate all of that. Thanks for your understanding in that matter.
